# Select only those columns that have values other than 0 | SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a table like this:

```
ID, ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD
---------------------------
10,   0,    4,    6,    9
11,   0,    3,    3,    8
```

When the sum of a given column > 0, I want to select it. So the number of columns in the query varies, based upon the sum.

Any suggestions would be great. I actually don't know how to proceed, so I do not have any code attempt so far.

Comment: If you want the number of columns to vary, then you need dynamic SQL.

Comment: I would suggest you to try a dynamic query. First make a sum for all 4 of your columns, then unpivot the result so you have a [ColName, Value] table. Make a filtering from you condition ( > 0 ) and you got the list of Column Names. Just put it in the dynamic query's select list.

Comment: You should explain what you actually want to do instead of posting a simplified example. Do you really want to return only the non-zero columns? Why not return all columns and let the *client* filter them? Or you could use a `SUM() OVER()` clause for each of those columns to retrieve the total sum in each row and use it to return NULL or 0 for the columns whose grand total is 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query should do what you want:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (ID INT, ColA INT, ColB INT, ColC INT, ColD INT)

INSERT INTO #temp VALUES
(10,   0,    4,    6,    9),
(11,   0,    3,    3,    8)

DECLARE @Col VARCHAR(100) = '';

SELECT @Col += ',' + [Col] FROM #temp
UNPIVOT (
Val for Col In ([ColA],[ColB],[ColC],[ColD]))unpiv
GROUP BY Col
HAVING SUM(Val) > 0;

SET @Col = STUFF(@Col,1,1,'');

EXEC ('SELECT [ID],'+@Col+' FROM #temp');
```

The result is as below,

```
ID  ColB  ColC  ColD
10  4     6     9
11  3     3     8
```

Comment: That's what I was referring to, but did not have the patience to write the unpivot...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this request sounds pretty wierd, it smells at bad design.

But still, if you want to achieve this, I would do it like this with dynamic SQL:

```
Declare @ShowColA bit
Declare @ShowColB bit
Declare @ShowColC bit
Declare @ShowColD bit
Declare @sqlCommand varchar(max)

IF (SELECT SUM(ColA) FROM yourTable) > 0
    SET @ShowColA = 1
IF (SELECT SUM(ColB) FROM yourTable) > 0
    SET @ShowColB = 1
IF (SELECT SUM(ColC) FROM yourTable) > 0
    SET @ShowColC = 1
IF (SELECT SUM(ColD) FROM yourTable) > 0
    SET @ShowColD = 1

SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT Id'
IF @ShowColA<> 0 SET @sqlCommand = @sqlCommand + ', ColA'
IF @ShowColB<> 0 SET @sqlCommand = @sqlCommand + ', ColB'
IF @ShowColC<> 0 SET @sqlCommand = @sqlCommand + ', ColC'
IF @ShowColD<> 0 SET @sqlCommand = @sqlCommand + ', ColD'
SET @sqlCommand = @sqlCommand + ' FROM yourTable'

EXEC @sqlCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the only possible values in the table are non-negatives. So you may try to sum a column by using SUM() and if it is 0 then don't take that one.

Comment: Please improve your answer by posting some example code to go along with your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEST
(
  ID INT
, COLA INT
, COLB INT
, COLC INT
, COLD INT
);

INSERT INTO #TEST VALUES
(
10,   0,    4,    6,    9
),
(
11,   0,    3,    3,    8
);

BEGIN 

DECLARE @COLLIST AS VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @RESULT AS INTEGER

SET @COLLIST = ''
SET @RESULT = (SELECT SUM(COLA) FROM #TEST)
IF @RESULT > 0
   SET @COLLIST = 'COLA'
SET @RESULT = (SELECT SUM(COLB) FROM #TEST)
IF @RESULT > 0
   IF @COLLIST <> ''
      SET @COLLIST = @COLLIST + ', '
   SET @COLLIST = @COLLIST + 'COLB'
SET @RESULT = (SELECT SUM(COLC) FROM #TEST)
IF @RESULT > 0
   IF @COLLIST <> ''
      SET @COLLIST = @COLLIST + ', '
   SET @COLLIST = @COLLIST + 'COLC'
SET @RESULT = (SELECT SUM(COLD) FROM #TEST)
IF @RESULT > 0
   IF @COLLIST <> ''
      SET @COLLIST = @COLLIST + ', '
   SET @COLLIST = @COLLIST + 'COLD'   

IF @COLLIST <> ''
   BEGIN
       PRINT ('SELECT ' + @COLLIST + ' FROM #TEST')
       EXEC ('SELECT ID, ' + @COLLIST + ' FROM #TEST')
   END

END
```

Result:

```
ID COLB COLC COLD
10  4   6   9
11  3   3   8
```